# Photoshop brush darkening and lighting

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I have run into a problem when working on a project, whenever I overlay a stroke it either darkens or lightens, (doesn't color properly) sometimes even changes the original color.

Its almost like the dodge/burn tool is going over it. How do I fix this?

[image: Example of what I'm talking about]

Comment: Are you working with layers that have different opacities?

Comment: No, I have this all on one layer.

Comment: Are you using a brush with a lowered opacity or fill?

Comment: No I am not, I have everything set like usual.

Comment: Is your brush tool set to Multiply or some blending mode in the top panel?

Answer (score 2):

Set your brush mode to Normal.